# How to reconcile difference in notation used in probability and statistics by different authors

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, self-learning, machine-learning

After learning probability for so many years, I still have trouble with the notation whenever I encounter a new reference. I have pinpointed my confusion to this "two-culture" of probability: one is the probability done by often-times engineers and people who write introductory textbooks on probability (e.g., Sheldon Ross), the other is done by statisticians and more recently practitioners of machine learning.

---

For the former (engineers and textbook writers), random variables are denoted as $X$, pdf are written as $f_X(x)$, jointed pdf are written as $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, where $x,y$ are in the range of random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Example: Sheldon Ross, Papolis and Pillai, Leon-Garcia, Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis, Feller, Kobayashi

[I found some notes online to illustrate this first culture of probability](https://homepages.wmich.edu/~bazuinb/ECE5820/Notes6.pdf)

---

For statistics and machine learning, random variables are not denoted as anything, they are suppressed, pdf is written as $p(x)$, where $x$ is the realization of this underlying unspecified random variable, joint pdf are written as $p(x,y)$. Capital letters are almost never used, always lowercase. However, sometimes lower case letter is used to denote a random variable, e.g., $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$

Example: Bishop, David MacKay, Hastie, Mohri

[I found some online notes to illustrate this second culture of probability](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/courses/CSC2515/Tutorial-ReviewProbability.pdf)

---

Am I correct in my assessment? Can someone who is familiar with this "two-culture" of probability provide a possible reconciliation between these notations?

Comment: This used to bother me alot when I started learning machine learning. Eventually, you just get used to it.

Comment: What's worse is when they use $x$ to mean the RV too. For instance, I often see entropy as $H[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians are stickers for full formal notation.

Statisticians and physicists get a little lazy and use abbreviations.  Their shorthand convenience does save space and as long it's clear what they mean it's...okay.

Just be careful.